# Use Built-in Messages in Inno Setup

Tags: internationalization, inno-setup

How can I use a built-in message in Inno Setup?

In "Default.isl" there is a message "FullInstallation" that I would like to use in my Inno Setup script. This message is therefore already translated in all languages that Inno Setup supports. It would save me from needing to do translations myself for this text.

I see that "Default.isl" has a `[CustomMessages]` section, and I can use these using (for example) `{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}` (since "CreateDesktopIcon" exists as a Custom Message).

How do I use one of the other messages not listed in the `[CustomMessages]` section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no [`{cm:...}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#cm) like constant by which you could expand a [`[Messages]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_messagessection.htm) entry. If I'm right, then it depends on where do you want to use such constant. If it's in the scripting part, then you'll need to use a [`scripted constant`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm) with a getter calling the [`SetupMessage`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_setupmessage.htm) function, by which you can expand those built-in messages for selected language by the constants listed in [`this file`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/MsgIDs.pas).

As you can notice, every message constant has just the `msg` prefix of the [`[Messages]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_messagessection.htm) entry from the language file.

For instance, to expand the `WizardPreparing` message into the [`Description`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#Description) value for the `[Run]` section entry you would expand the `msgWizardPreparing` constant this way:

```
[Run]
Filename: "MyProg.exe"; Description: "{code:GetDescription}"

[Code]
function GetDescription(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := SetupMessage(msgWizardPreparing);
end;
```

In the `[Code]` section is the situation naturally easier, since the [`SetupMessage`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_setupmessage.htm) function you can use directly there. So, for instance, to show a message box with the expanded `CannotContinue` message you'd expand the `msgCannotContinue` constant simply this way:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := SetupMessage(msgCannotContinue);
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: I am trying to use it in the scripted part, but this is a good solution if there is no direct way to do it.

Comment: For the script part there is just this function. I would say that there won't be any constant for this since the purpose of those messages is primarily just for the internal use.